# Binding CheckedListBox to settings

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I'm attempting to build a CheckedListBox in WPF and bind it to the user settings so that it is constructed once only and then updates the settings automatically in XAML using `ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Settings.Default}, Path=Customers, Mode=TwoWay}`

I can see the checkboxes but they don't show the Customer name and don't retain their values in settings. Is anyone able to spot why?

I think I may need to cast from the settings to the current Customers ObservableCollection but can't get this working?

Customers = Properties.Settings.Default.Customers.Cast;

**TestSettings.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.TestSettings"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Properties"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="TestSettings" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
    <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Settings.Default}, Path=Customers, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="12,22,12,79">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Path=Item.CustomerName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**TestSettings.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for TestSettings.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class TestSettings : Window
    {

        public ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Customer>> Customers { get; set; }

        public class Customer
        {
            public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        }

        public TestSettings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (Properties.Settings.Default.Customers == null)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer> 
                { 
                        new Customer() { CustomerName = "Kelly Smith" },
                        new Customer() { CustomerName = "Joe Brown" },
                        new Customer() { CustomerName = "Herb Dean" }

                    //Customers.Add(new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer(){CustomerName="Kelly Smith"}));
                    //Customers.Add(new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer(){CustomerName="Joe Brown"}));
                    //Customers.Add(new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer(){CustomerName="Herb Dean"}));

                };
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
            else
            {
               // Customers = (ObservableCollection<Customer>)Properties.Settings.Default.Customers;
            }
        }

        public class CheckedListItem<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            private bool isChecked;
            private T item;

            public CheckedListItem()
            { }

            public CheckedListItem(T item, bool isChecked = false)
            {
                this.item = item;
                this.isChecked = isChecked;
            }

            public T Item
            {
                get { return item; }
                set
                {
                    item = value;
                    if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item"));
                }
            }


            public bool IsChecked
            {
                get { return isChecked; }
                set
                {
                    isChecked = value;
                    if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsChecked"));
                }
            }
        }

        private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

**Settings.Designer.cs**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.269
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
namespace WpfApplication1.Properties
{


    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "10.0.0.0")]
    internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase
    {

        private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

        public static Settings Default
        {
            get
            {
                return defaultInstance;
            }

        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        public ObservableCollection<WpfApplication1.TestSettings.Customer> Customers
        {
            get
            {
                return ((ObservableCollection<WpfApplication1.TestSettings.Customer>)(this["Customers"]));
            }
            set
            {
                this["Customers"] = value;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call Settings.Default.Save() after you change a settings value or before you allow the user to leave the page. Either add it to the setter for your settings value or make a Save Settings button.

Comment: I have that already in the Window_Closing event.

Comment: I only see it in your constructor method.

Comment: I've been moving it about whilst testing so missed it off when copying here.

Comment: well, then in theory it should be working. The only possible explanation is that your checkboxes are not actually being data bound.

Comment: I suggest instead of using auto properties, you expand them so you can put break points in the getters and setters to see if any of it is being used.

Comment: They're not firing, that's definitely the problem. But I can't figure out how to intitialize `public ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Customer>> Customers { get; set; }` from the settings?

Comment: ah well, you will probably need to use reflection then. Try something like set { var property = Settings.Default.GetType().GetProperty(customerName); return property.GetValue(Settings.Default, null) as string; } That might not work, but reflection should be the key, I honestly don't use it, but I hope this can point you down the right path.

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson - thanks for your help. Your advice jogged me in to realising what the problem was. I've posted a working answer - thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - Sorted.

There were 2 main problems

1/ I was only adding CustomerName and not the CheckListItem so

`ObservableCollection<Customer>`  should be `ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Customer>>`

2/ Same again adding the customers.

`new Customer() { CustomerName = "Kelly Smith" }` should be `new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer() { CustomerName = "Kelly Smith" })`

So full working code is

**Settings.Designer.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
namespace WpfApplication1.Properties {


    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "10.0.0.0")]
    internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

        private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

        public static Settings Default {
            get {
                return defaultInstance;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        public ObservableCollection<WpfApplication1.TestSettings.CheckedListItem<WpfApplication1.TestSettings.Customer>> Customers
        {
            get
            {
                return ((ObservableCollection<WpfApplication1.TestSettings.CheckedListItem<WpfApplication1.TestSettings.Customer>>)(this["Customers"]));
            }
            set
            {
                this["Customers"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**TestSettings.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.TestSettings"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Properties"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="TestSettings" Height="300" Width="300" Closing="Window_Closing">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Settings.Default}, Path=Customers, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="12,22,12,79">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Path=Item.CustomerName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**TestSettings.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for TestSettings.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class TestSettings : Window
    {

        public ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Customer>> Customers
        {
            get;
            set;
        }


        public class Customer
        {
            public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        }

        public TestSettings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (Properties.Settings.Default.Customers == null)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.Customers = new ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Customer>>
                { 
                        new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer() { CustomerName = "Kelly Smith" }),
                        new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer() { CustomerName = "Joe Brown" }),
                        new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer() { CustomerName = "Herb Dean" }),
                        new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer() { CustomerName = "fg4" }),
                        new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer() { CustomerName = "fg5" }),
                        new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer() { CustomerName = "fg6" }),
                        new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer() { CustomerName = "fg7" }),
                        new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer() { CustomerName = "fg8" }),
                        new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer() { CustomerName = "fg9" }),
                        new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer() { CustomerName = "fg10" }),
                        new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer() { CustomerName = "fg11" }),
                        new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer() { CustomerName = "fg12" }),
                        new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer() { CustomerName = "fg13" }),
                        new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer() { CustomerName = "fg14" })

                };
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

            }
            else
            {
                //var a = Properties.Settings.Default.Customers;
                //Customers = ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<>>;

            }
        }

        public class CheckedListItem<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            private bool isChecked;
            private T item;

            public CheckedListItem()
            { }

            public CheckedListItem(T item, bool isChecked = false)
            {
                this.item = item;
                this.isChecked = isChecked;
            }

            public T Item
            {
                get { return item; }
                set
                {
                    item = value;
                    if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item"));
                }
            }


            public bool IsChecked
            {
                get { return isChecked; }
                set
                {
                    isChecked = value;
                    if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsChecked"));
                }
            }
        }

        private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: It appears that this does work but as the `Settings.Designer.cs` has been amended the settings don't persist between separate run-times as generic types cannot be stored in the settings. Rather than change Settings.Designer.cs I've ended up created and XML string which gets saved in the settings as a string and then build ObservableCollection> from the XML and vice versa.